# Can't change song in jPlayer after setting media

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

I have some jQuery working that starts a jPlayer playing an MP3 as shown below

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function () { 
          $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", { 
            mp3: mp3_url

          });
          $(this).jPlayer("play", 0);
        },
        swfPath: "/js",
        supplied: "mp3",

      });
```

This works fine. But when I try to change the song to another mp3 I can't. I run the same function but with a different `mp3_url` to no avail. I know the function is being called and that the arguments are being passed correctly. It is getting inside the function (tested with `alert();`) but don't know why it won't change the song?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: please show the code you are using to change the song

Comment: u need tu use the detroy or clearmedia before setting the new 1 ..

Comment: Would you mind to show some code on how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem. Thanks for help anyway.

Here is the code

```
function updatePlayer(name, artist, guid){
        var player = $("#jquery_jplayer_1");

        player.jPlayer({
        ready: function () { 
          $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", { 
            mp3: guid

          }); 
          $(this).jPlayer("play", 0);
        },
        swfPath: "/js",
        supplied: "mp3",

      }); 
      player.jPlayer("setMedia", { 
            mp3: guid
          }); 
      player.jPlayer("play", 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Just like this:

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("destroy");
```

[Jplayer('destroy') documentation](http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-destroy)